# Postsharp - Introduced virtual method is called instead overriden method

Tags: c#, postsharp

Aspect looks like this

```
[Serializable] 
[IntroduceInterface(typeof(ISomeMethod), OverrideAction = InterfaceOverrideAction.Ignore)] 
public class MyAspect: InstanceLevelAspect, ISomeMethod 
{ 
    [IntroduceMember(IsVirtual = true, OverrideAction = MemberOverrideAction.Ignore)] 
    public string SomeMethod() 
    { 
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }

    [OnMethodInvokeAdvice, MulticastPointcut(Targets = MulticastTargets.Method, Attributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)] 
    public void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args) 
    { 
        var something = args.Instance as ISomeMethod;

        //here is problem
        string str = something.SomeMethod();

        args.Proceed(); 
    } 
}
```

When i check it in dotPeek, SomeMethod is introduced and is virtual. Aspect is applied to base class that is in different project as child classes. Problem is when i override this method and OnInvoke interceptor is called, SomeMethod in aspect is actually called with NotImplementedException instead of overriden method. Debugger confirmed i have right instance in args.Instance. How is this possible? Thanks for answer.

Comment: what does your code where you are trying to overwrite the method look like?

Comment: more code http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/3039-introduced-virtual-method-called-instead-overriden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug which is <s>going to be solved in future version of PostSharp</s> solved since PostSharp 4.2.22/4.3.5.

**The rest of the original answer:**

But there is a workaround.

Let me visualize the code described in the question. The base class in project A would look like this:

```
[MyAspect]
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public void InterceptedMethod(string message)
    {
    }
}
```

The child class in project B reproducing the bug would look like this:

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public override string SomeMethod()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

The workaround for now is to implement the interface method instead of overriding it.

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass, ISomeMethod
{
    public string SomeMethod()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i was fixed to the design of my classes and this bug so much i didn't notice such easy workaround that will be sufficient for what i am trying to accomplish :)